# List obs variable in GetX Controller still empty after added value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

When i add value to an obs list in GetX controller inside a function, it shows the length that the data is successfully added. But when i call the variable in another function, the list is still empty.

```
class ExampleController extends GetxController {
  var dataList = <dynamic>[].obs;

  void setImages(items) {
    dataList.addAll(items);
    log(dataList.length.toString()); // shows the data length after added items
  }

  void onButtonPressed() {
    log(dataList.length.toString()); // shows 0 length
  }
}
```

I put the controller like this ..

```
void main {
  runApp(const myApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.put(ExampleController());

    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'GetX Example',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how i instantiate the controller..

```
class DataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DataPage> createState() => _DataPageState();
}

class _DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
  final _exampleController = Get.find<ExampleController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: CustomButtonIcon(
          label: 'Get Data',
          onPressed: () => _exampleController.onButtonPressed(),
          icon: Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This indicates an error in the program flow. Do you manipulate `dataList` in other places? Also, you may have instantiated the controller `ExampleController` twice and just assume that you use the same controller: `Get.find() vs Get.put()` .

Comment: @Dabbel no, i only try to debug the data and it isn't there. Set and get it all in the same controller file.

Comment: Please show more code: how the Controller gets instantiated `Get.put() / Get.find() ...`

Comment: i do it like usual, and only call the function inside controller file and one stateful widget to call the onButtonPressed() function @Dabbel

Comment: Use a `class DataPage extends StatelessWidget`, as the point of Getx is that `StatefulWidget` is not necessary. Also, please show the invokation of `setImages()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the `setImages()` function . But never called .

So the List obs variable in Controller is empty.

To work as expected.
Before the `onButtonPressed()` function call the `setImages()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
 void setImages(items) {
    dataList.addAll(items);
    log(dataList.length.toString()); // shows the data length after added items

     update(); // use this
  }
```

---

```
  void onButtonPressed() {

Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    log(dataList.length.toString()); // shows 0 length

});
  }
```

Comment: it's still not working.

Comment: add future delay check the updated answer